# How do I change my sword in assassin's creed 2

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I bought the sword of Altair and want to fight with it but I have the Florentine Falchion equipped.

Answer (score 6):

You need to go to your Villa and go to the armory/weapons room (it's to your left when you enter), you can change your equipment there. The room right after that is where you can switch out armor sets.